# How to dynamically create two inputs placeholder in render ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

My class is calculating the hours between **two** places given the hour and minute at each place. I would like to change the `<Input>` part such that I don't have to repeat myself. The function time is taking two parameters the "hour" and the "minute". I tried but could not figure out. Please help.

```
updateTime(time, value){
    let clock = this.state.time;
    clock[time] = value;
    this.setState(clock);
}
render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Card>
          <CardBody>
            <InputGroup>
              <InputGroupAddon addonType={"prepend"}> Hour Origin</InputGroupAddon>
              <Input placeholder=“1” onChange={(event)=> this.updateTime(‘hour’,event.target.value)}/>
              <InputGroupAddon addonType={"prepend"}>Minute Origin</InputGroupAddon>
              <Input placeholder=“1” onChange={(event)=> this.updateTime(‘minute’, event.target.value)}/>
            </InputGroup>

            <InputGroup>
              <InputGroupAddon addonType={"prepend"}> Hour Destination</InputGroupAddon>
              <Input placeholder=“1” onChange={(event)=> this.updateTime(‘hour’,event.target.value)}/>
              <InputGroupAddon addonType={"prepend"}>Hour Destination</InputGroupAddon>
              <Input placeholder=“1” onChange={(event)=> this.updateTime(‘minute’, event.target.value)}/>
            </InputGroup>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can package the `InputGroup`s in components and then render the components.

Here's an example:

```
const HourMinuteInputGroup = props => {
    const { locationName, updateTime } = props;

    return (
        <InputGroup>
            <InputGroupAddon addonType={"prepend"}>Hour { locationName }</InputGroupAddon>
            <Input placeholder="1" onChange={ event => updateTime('hour',event.target.value) }/>
            <InputGroupAddon addonType={"prepend"}>Minute { locationName }</InputGroupAddon>
            <Input placeholder="1" onChange={ event => updateTime('minute', event.target.value) }/>
        </InputGroup>
    )
}
```

Then your original `render` becomes:

```
render(){
    return(
    <div>
        <Card>
            <CardBody>
                <HourMinuteInputGroup locationName="Origin" updateTime={ this.updateTime }/>
                <HourMinuteInputGroup locationName="Destination" updateTime={ this.updateTime }/>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I would assume the HourMinuteInputGroup will be outside of the render. But if I have const HourMinuteInputGroup it gives me error

Comment: Ideally `HourMinuteInputGroup` should be defined in another file and exported. Then in the file that contains your main `render`, import `HourMinuteInputGroup` and then you should be able to use the component. They can both be defined in the same file, but note that `HourMinuteInputGroup` is a component and shouldn't be defined within whatever component your `render` function is for

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate it